# Inserting row in pandas dataframe based on time using datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two dataframes as show below:

```
df1 = 
index                 value

2014-05-21 09:30:00    0.0       
2014-05-21 10:00:00   10.0
2014-05-21 10:30:00    3.0

.....

2017-07-10 22:30:00   18.3
2017-07-10 23:00:00    7.6
2017-07-10 23:30:00    0.0
```

the length is equal to *55037* , and the other one

```
df2 = 
index                 value

2014-05-21 09:00:00    0.0
2014-05-21 10:00:00   13.0

.....

2017-07-10 21:00:00    1.6
2017-07-10 22:00:00   32.1
2017-07-10 23:00:00    7.6
```

the length is equal to *27519*, the two dataframe above are groupby with different time step, now I would like to match the time step *in the beginning and end* automatic.

For example, the "2014-05-21 09:00:00" is lack in *df1*, how can I write a function, put the *df1* and it would check if the *beginning and end* matched 
 *df2*, then return a new *df1* which in the beginning and end equal to *df2* and the value equal to zero.

so in the end the new df1 would as show below,

```
new_df1 = 
index                 value

2014-05-21 09:00:00    0.0 
2014-05-21 09:30:00    0.0       
2014-05-21 10:00:00   10.0
2014-05-21 10:30:00    3.0

 .....

2017-07-10 22:30:00   18.3
2017-07-10 23:00:00    7.6
2017-07-10 23:30:00    0.0
```

and length equal to *55038* (make sure it is two times large than *df2*)

Anyone have idea ? Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Try to make a [mcve]. This looks like some sort of merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need add all rows by missing dates from `df2.index` need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2)
print (df)
                     value
2014-05-21 09:00:00    0.0 <- value not exist in df1, used df2 value
2014-05-21 09:30:00    0.0
2014-05-21 10:00:00   10.0 <-value exist in both df, used df1 value
2014-05-21 10:30:00    3.0
2017-07-10 21:00:00    1.6
2017-07-10 22:00:00   32.1
2017-07-10 22:30:00   18.3
2017-07-10 23:00:00    7.6
2017-07-10 23:30:00    0.0
```

Comment: Thanks ! tt really helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can select df1 where the index matches the beginning and end of df2.

```
df1.loc[beginning(df2):end(df2)]
```

You'll want to make sure that the items are really in order for df1 because it will return the locs between beginning and end in order. If the timestamp is a datetime object, it will correctly sort if you call df1.sort_index(). You will also be able to get the beginning and end of df2 by calling df2.index.min() and df2.index.min()

If the timestamps are strings, but you can be sure that the items are in order, you can still use the .loc to select. Otherwise you'll want to convert them to datetime objects.